# ARRAY DEVUELVE VACÍO CUANDO LO CONVIERTO A JSON EN JAVASCRIPT

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

les comparto un error muy particular que tengo, para resolver esto es necesario descargar el código que lo pueden encontrar en: [codigo-fuente](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tXl8LP8sel9JbINYieyYq9S25m8QyKc8/view?usp=sharing)

Tengo un arreglo global llamado "fileLimpio" en la cual inserto información cuando ejecuto un AJAX en JQUERY y PHP. La primera validación que se hizo es que si estaba almacenando la información en el array correctamente. console.log(fileLimpio)

```
var fileLimpio = new Array();

for (let i = 0; i < filesvar.length; i++) {
                    let archivo = filesvar[i];
                    let datos = new FormData();
                    datos.append("archivo", archivo);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "ajax/shipmentFile.php",
                        method: "POST",
                        data: datos,
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        success: function(respuesta){
                            fileLimpio.push({
                                        file: respuesta.slice(3),
                                    });
                            
                        }
                    });
                }

                console.log("resultado de hacer un array push", fileLimpio);
```

Pero el problema esta cuando intento convertir ese array en formato JSON mediante:

```
console.log("convirtiendo el array en JSON", JSON.stringify(fileLimpio));
```

Al parecer todo está bien, la información en el array y la estructura que es importante, pero, por alguna razón que ya desconozco hace varios días no se imprime el JSON convertido. Cualquier duda se pueden descargar el código y se dirigen a: views/modules/ord-embarque.php linea 873 y la url para acceder al formulario de prueba es: http://tu_localhost/simulation_error_eibu/ord-embarque

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Hola recuerda que AJAX es asíncrono, por lo tanto cuando haces console.log() fuera del AJAX es probable que el console.log() te muestre [] o no se convierta correctamente a JSON.

Lo que debes asegurarte es que la petición AJAX terminé por completo y recién imprimir el valor del array y hacer la conversión a JSON.

El código quedaría así.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "ajax/shipmentFile.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: datos,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        }).done(function(respuesta){
          fileLimpio.push({
                             file: respuesta.slice(3),
                          });
           console.log("resultado de hacer un array push", fileLimpio);
           console.log("convirtiendo el array en JSON",JSON.stringify(fileLimpio));
       });
```

Ojo: Lo probé con datos falsos ya que no tenía la base de datos.

```
var fileLimpio = new Array();
fileLimpio.push({file: "../security_administrator/views/dist/img/shipment/shipment.pdf".slice(3)})
```

Y el resultado del console.log() es esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y la conversión es este:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: gracias Clinton, me ayudo mucho la teoría y el código que pusiste, mil gracias!

Comment: Clinton, quiero imprimir en json fuera del for ya que probablemente el for se ejcute varias veces y quiero finalmente tener un solo array con el json de todo lo que recorra ese for.